# ReentrantReadWriteLock getReadHoldCount vs getReadLockCount

Tags: java, concurrency

what is the difference between getReadHoldCount and getReadLockCount of ReentrantReadWriteLock?

Comment: What part of the documentation didn't you understand?

Comment: I read the documentation in the IDE (multiple times) and missed the words "by the current thread" that made the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of the methods:

[`getReadHoldCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#getReadHoldCount--): *Returns the number of holds on the read lock **by the current thread**, or zero if the read lock is not held by the current thread.*

[`getReadLockCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#getReadLockCount--): *Returns the number of read locks held.*

Remember, a thread may call [`lock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock.html#lock--) on the `ReadLock` multiple times, which will only take one actual lock, but each call to `lock()` must be matched by a call to [`unlock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock.html#unlock--) before the actual lock is released.

The lock count is the number of threads that has a read-lock.

There is a corresponding method for write lock:

[`getWriteHoldCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#getWriteHoldCount--): *Returns the number of holds on the write lock **by the current thread**, or zero if the write lock is not held by the current thread.*

Same as before, the thread may hold the write lock multiple times.

So why is there no `getWriteLockCount()`? Because at most one thread can have a write lock, so there's no point in returning a count. A boolean is enough: [`isWriteLocked()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#isWriteLocked--): *Returns true if any thread holds the write lock and false otherwise.*